# Need advice about VCR to PC connection

Tags: usb, video, capture

I need advice for something I want to do with VCR to PC image transfering.
I have bought a video capture usb (RCA to usb) but there is a problem with the image... It's shaking right and left.
Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwtqqhVU0I4

Firstly, let me tell you that when I connect the VCR to the TV the image is fine.
Also when I connect a DVD player (a device way newer than the VCR) to the PC through the same usb, the image is also fine.
So, something must be wrong when the analog-to-digital signal converting is happening.
It's like the TV sees this problematic image and has a way to fix it somehow.
On the other hand, the usb doesn't have a way to fix it, so I have this shaking image.

So, my questions is... 
What are the possible explanations/causes for this??
Usb device quality?? VCR quality?? 
What system has a TV to fix a VCR shaking image??
Is there a software or some settings for PC that do the same fix a TV does??

Thank you.

(if you don't know about video capture usbs, can you please give me a link with people who know more about these devices?? Some digital engineers maybe??)

Comment: Have you tried a different video tape?

Comment: Is the shaking of the image affected if you move the cable?

Comment: Yes, every tape is the same. No, there isn't any change if I move the cable.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of distortions on the recorded video suggests that the signal at the RCA-to-USB converter input has copyright protection.

If the tape has copyrighted video material, it might have the Macrovision thechique of [embedding fake pulses](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/question313.htm) that a TV can filter out, but an automatic gain control in your "a video capture RCA to USB" board can't.

Some VCRs would include this scrambling into output video stream, as mentioned in [THIS article](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs201/projects/1999-00/dmca-2k/macrovision.html). You may want to try some other VCR that doesn't do this.

Comment: Who told you that it's copyrighted video material??
They are private VHS that I used to record things on TV when I was a kid.
I personally filled them, so they haven't anything copyrighted.

Comment: @Alexinho25, the shape of distortions told me.

Comment: I don't know if it's a similar shape, but I can assure you it's not copyrighted.

Comment: @Alexinho25, then it is your VCR that adds the scrambling, http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs201/projects/1999-00/dmca-2k/macrovision.html Okay, I will re-write the answer.